# unused argument in function in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and trying to use the acceptance rejection method to generate a standard normal variable as part of an an assignment and I can't figure out where I'm off in defining this function.  I've looked through other cases with the unused argument error, but they seem to be related to having extra variables as input, which I don't believe I do.  Can someone explain why this happens?  I would really like to understand better how R works.

```
AR<-function(u1,u2){
    y1=(-1)*(log(u1))
    y2=(-1)*(log(u2))
    condition=(((y1)-1)*((y1)-1))/2
    u3=runif(1)
    ifelse(u3>=0.5,zz=abs(z),zz=(-1)*(abs(z)))
}

u1=runif(1)
u2=runif(1)
AR(u1,u2)
# Error in ifelse(u3 >= 0.5, zz = abs(z), zz = (-1) * (abs(z))) : 
#  unused argument(s) (zz = abs(z), zz = (-1) * (abs(z)))
```

Comment: notice that in general it is preferable to use `<-` for assignments rather than `=`

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to get that.  I modified it as, @sgibb mentioned below, and ran it as **`zz=AR(u1,u2)`**, where u1 and u2 are just **`runif(1)`**.  Would it work also when calling the function to have said **`zz <- AR(u1,u2)`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` has no arguments called `zz` (the names are `test, yes, no`, see `?ifelse`). That's why you get the error `unused arguments`. The correct usage of `ifelse` would be:

```
zz <- ifelse(u3 >= 0.5, abs(z), (-1) * abs(z))
```

Comment: Okay, that does take care of it.  So I wouldn't be able to use ifelse if it had been two different variables then, is that right?  Like if I wanted to set a=expr for true and b=expr for false I would have to do it a different way? Can I use equivalence operators inside of a regular if statement or does it work similarly to the ifelse if I try to do that?

Comment: You can imbed ifelse in iflese like `zz <- ifelse(u3 >= 0.5, abs(z),  ifelse(u3 >= 0.25, (-1) * abs(z), abs(z) * 2))`